# Dynamic nested routers in Apache Camel for (from endpoint)

Tags: apache-camel

I want to create a routers as below

`<camel:from uri="jms:queue:sample.queue.demo1" />
       <camel:from uri="${header.location1}" />
       <camel:to uri="${header.location2}" />
   <camel:to uri="jms:queue:sample.queue.demo2" />`

Does Our Apache Camel implement the above scenarios?

How to achieve the above scenarios with our Apache Camel.

Note: I am using the Apache Camel 2.13.0 version

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [enrichment pattern](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) to do such things.

However, you cannot really do "dynamic from" with polling consumers, such as file folders etc. The same goes if you want to start listening for http traffic (not just poll a URL).

You can fire up new Camel routes in a java bean, or similar for such scenarios.